# Verify that $\sinh x\simeq x$?

Tags: asymptotics, hyperbolic-functions

In fact, I came across the following statement:
$$
\frac{\sinh ix}{\sinh ix+i\cosh ix}\simeq\sinh x\simeq x.
$$
Unfortunately, the claim by itself is incomplete, as it is not clear what $x$ is. (Is it real/complex? Is it large/small?)

A likely argumentation is the following: Since
$$
\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\simeq\sin x\simeq x\quad\text{for $x$ sufficiently small}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sinh ix}{\sinh ix+i\cosh ix}=\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x},
$$
we have
$$
\frac{\sinh ix}{\sinh ix+i\cosh ix}\simeq\sin x\simeq x.
$$
But $\sinh x\simeq\sin x$ for $x$ sufficiently small, which yields the statement.

I would like to provide a more detailed verification (e.g. using series expansion), especially to see if under the condition that $x$ be sufficiently small the approximation will indeed be valid. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: What is unclear is what $\;\simeq\;$ is here...

Comment: Are you asking whether $\sinh x$ is asymptotic to $x$, i.e. $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sinh x}{x}=1 \, ?$$This is certainly true, as the derivative of $\sinh$ is $\cosh$, and $\cosh(0)=1$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It means approximately equal to (equivalently written $\approx$).

Comment: $\sinh x=\dfrac{x^1}{1!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$

Comment: @Joe: Cheers. So asymptotically, as $x$ is sufficiently small, it holds true that $
\frac{\sinh ix}{\sinh ix+i\cosh ix}\simeq\sinh x\simeq x
$. This is clear. But is there e.g. a power series verification of this?

Comment: @Trevor3: Does J.W. Tanner's comment answer your question? In any case, bear in mind that $\approx$ is not a formally defined symbol. The precise statement is that $\sinh x \sim x$, which is a shorthand for saying that $\sinh x$ is asymptotic to $x$.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks. Yes, J.W. Tanner's comment answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sinh x=\dfrac {x^1}{1!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$,

so asymptotically $\sinh x\sim x$ as $x\to0$ in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.